# Reusing Propel query bug or my bad?

Tags: php, orm, propel

Simple [Propel reusing query](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#reusing_a_query) is not working here, despite my code is similar to the example on Propel website. ***Is this a bug or my bad?***

```
$q = MashupSettingQuery::create()->filterByMashup($this);
var_dump($q->count(), $q->findOneByKey('redirect_uri'), $q->count());
```

Output is:

```
int 5

object(MashupSetting)[28]
  protected 'startCopy' => boolean false
  protected 'id' => int 9
  protected 'key' => string 'redirect_uri' (length=12)

int 1
```

that is, resusing is not working because `count()` first returns 5 and then 1.

Even using `MashupSettingQuery::create()->filterByMashup($this)->keepQuery(true)` didn't fix the problem.

Comment: According to the doc, it should work.. Otherwise, you found a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's normal because just before the second count you make a findOneByKey query, and so the second count just count how many objects this specific query return.
And your query return just one object, obviously because it's a findOneByKey.

Comment: Maxime is right. But, find* are terminaison methods, so it should not impact the query, which is not the case obviously. findOneByKey will add a filterKey() and a limit(1) to the query.

Comment: @WilliamDURAND so how one can reuse queries in Propel? What's wrong in my example?

Comment: If you want to execute twice a command you need to create two command variable.
Like:
    $q = MashupSettingQuery::create()->filterByMashup($this);
    $q2 = clone $q;
    $q->findSomething();
    $q2->findSomethingElse();

Comment: As described in the docs http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#reusing-a-query the `findOneByKey` method should not modify the count, instead the count should remain stable. I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: The url you provided is the Propel 2 documentation, and the question was for Propel 1.x.